# C++ Saving and reading class objects to and from file. What is the best option?

Tags: c++, class, text, binary, filestream

I want to put my double linked list of Students into file and then read them. My double linked list works fine, has every crucial feature now. Relevant to this task may be:

```
void addToChain(Student& BeeingAddedStudent);
void removeLastLink();
int  howManyLinks();
friend ostream& operator << (ostream&, Chain&);
friend ofstream& operator << (ofstream&, Chain&);
```

Student looks like this:

```
class Student
{
    string First;
    string Last;
    string* Classes; //array of classes student attend **(MAY BE PHRASES WITH FEW WORDS)**
    int Id, N; //student's ID in university system and number of classes
    double Avg; //average grade

public:
    Student();
    Student(Student&);
    ~Student();

    ... //Full list of accessors

    Student& operator=(Student&);
    friend ostream& operator << (ostream&, Student&);
    friend ofstream& operator << (ofstream&, Student&);

}
```

Now, what do you think will be best choice to store this objects? I don't want to have an insight into a file. Can you please explain me, how exchange this objects with files? I know basic commands, but have no idea which methods of fstream should i use. Here's, what i started with, so your answer can be short and comprehensive:

```
void Chain::saveToFile()
{
    ofstream file;
    file.open("Data.cha");
    file << *this;
    file.close();
}

void Chain::loadFromFile()
{
    while (StartLink->Essence != NULL)
        this->removeLastLink();
    ifstream file;
    file.open("Data.cha");
    Student current;
    while (!EOF)
    {
        //I have no idea, what should i put here...
    }

}
```

As you see, i started working with textfiles, but if you think, that's fine, i will love to change it to binary...

Comment: Use mode parameter ios::binary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Best choice" depends on what you rate high.

You can add to/fromBinaryFile methods to your class, for which you'll have to define a byte array memory layout. This should be fastest.

You can add to/fromText methods to your class, for which you'll have to define textual representations. This will be tolerant against changes in the internal representation, but conversion to and from text requires extra effort. It'll also (usually) require a little more disk space.

You can define an XML layout and use some XML library for reading and writing XML documents. This is the most complex, but you'll be free from all worries about textual representation, and data will be ready for interoparibility with any other program capable of reading/writing XML and there are nice things like XSLT. In a sense, this will also be tolerant against extensions of your class.

Comment: What do you mean by "byte array memory layout"? I searched the Web, but can't find anything similar, sorry. Could you give an example for object with:
`string S;
int I;`,
how can i do it?

Comment: For an int32_t you'll need 4 byte. For a std::string, either use the C represenation, chars followed by a '\0', or a length (int8_t, int16_t) followed by as many chars, and so on. You concatenate the bytes of ints and strings into a byte array, whose length may have to be computed dynamically. Then, the composed byte array is written to the file. - Yes, that's low-level, but that's how serialization (= the process of writing object data to a file) works in this case. - You may prefer the second option.

Comment: Second option is easier, i think so too. But now i have problem with other thing. I store list of my student's classes as second line, where classes are separated by `','`. It goes like `Mathematics,Linear Algebra,Physical Education Adv, Optics,`. If i  read this to one string, how can i divide it, so temp1 will get Mathematics, temp2 Linear Algera and so on...?

Comment: You'll have to read it to several strings. Best to read a line, and then "read" strings from that line until it is exhausted. There are many options for parsing string data...